# Not able to access php file

Tags: javascript, php, directory-structure

I have reorganized my directory structure and my php file is not being used/called. It's as if I can't access it. My functions and the php file were working as expected before this and my file permissions are sorted out so can someone lead me in the right direction?

The directory is as follows:

```
public_html(folder)
  - javascript(folder)
    - main(folder)
      - userManagement.js => The `tryEmail` function is in here.
  - php(folder)
    - users-profs(folder)
      - tryEmail.php
  - index.html
```

The code:

```
 function tryEmail(email)
    {
        console.log("function:tryEmail, param: " + email);
        return function()
        {
            $.post("../../php/users-profs/tryEmail.php",
            {
                email:email
            },
            function(data)
            {
                console.log("function:tryEmail-post, data: " + data);
                if(data == "valid")
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you determining it's not being loaded/called? Check your error logs because that's the usually the key to what's wrong. My guess it there's some sort of path that's wrong or perms/open dir limitations

Comment: I have error reporting enabled in php and I echo a statement under every circumstance and I don't get a response at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `../../php/users-profs/tryEmail.php` will be interpreted relative to the user's current URL, not the URL of the `.js` file. Match the URL in `$.post()` to the URL where you will invoke this script, and it will be fine.

**Edit based on comment:** Add a slash: `/php/users-profs/tryEmail.php` -- without it, it's a relative URL, so it's looking in the wrong place.

Also, you need to remove the anonymous wrapper function, because you can't return an anonymous function, and it won't execute anyway. Your code should look like this:

```
function tryEmail(email)
{
    console.log("function:tryEmail, param: " + email);
    $.post("/php/users-profs/tryEmail.php", // fixed the leading / here
        {
            email:email
        },
        function(data)
        {
            console.log("function:tryEmail-post, data: " + data);
            if(data == "valid")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        });
}
```

Comment: I used the path `php/users-profs/tryEmail.php` because it's invoked in my index file (I edited the question to show it) and I'm still getting nothing.

Comment: Add a slash: `/php/users-profs/tryEmail.php` -- without it, it's a relative URL, so it's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have also tried this. I don't have a clue what the problem is.

Comment: What, if anything, is happening? Is the `console.log()` firing like you expect? Are you seeing error messages (and if so, what are they)?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors via the console or the post data from the php file. I get `function:tryEmail, param: *******@uwplatt.edu` in the console so the function is being called.

Comment: Based on your code above, that means the `$.post()` succeeded.  The anonymous `function(data)` is triggered only when `$.post()` succeeds, and the fact that you are seeing data means your PHP script returned (echoed) that info.

Comment: I believe you misread that. The console logs `function:tryEmail` but the result from the post should write `function:tryEmail-post` to the console. Easy to mix up.

Comment: You're right. I can't believe I missed this: take out the `return function() {` and corresponding `}`. That is an invalid return value, which will cause a problem.

Comment: It was the wrapper function around the post that wasn't working. I don't know why it was working previously and isn't now but I removed it and it worked. I've accepted this because Without that function I was still traversing up the directory tree because I didn't know that the path was relative to location that it was invoked from. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. No clue why the wrapper function worked before, but yeah, that's a problem. I'm going to add it to my answer in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
"../../php/users-profs/tryEmail.php"
```

use your project's base url and then concatenate your file location to it like

```
<your_project_base_url> + 'php/users-profs/tryEmail.php'
```

Comment: I've also tried the absolute path ... `var/www/...` and am getting no results.

Comment: try this

var base_url = '<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>';

and then use that "base_url" variable as

base_url + 'php/users-profs/tryEmail.php'

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll use this in the future. I made a mistake elsewhere though.